# ansible on RHEL 6.5 hangs with python deprecation warning

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to use ansible to deploy code to my RHEL 6.5 server. It came with python 2.6.6 installed. Whenever I try to run a playbook it hangs here:

```
$ ansible-playbook --ask-vault-pass deploy.yml -vvvv
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Vault password: 
Loaded callback default of type stdout, v2.0
1 plays in deploy.yml

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
<my.host.com> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: root on PORT 22 TO my.host.com
<my.host.com> EXEC mkdir -p "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1455138572.23-19937147316183 )" && echo "$( echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1455138572.23-19937147316183 )"
<my.host.com> PUT /tmp/tmpahc0Pq TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1455138572.23-19937147316183/setup
<my.host.com> EXEC LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1455138572.23-19937147316183/setup; rm -rf "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1455138572.23-19937147316183/" > /dev/null 2>&1
^CTraceback (most recent call last):

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
```

I ssh into my server and attempt to run the code that it hangs on and get the following python(?) deprecation and then it hangs:

```
$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1455138572.23-19937147316183/setup; rm -rf "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1455138572.23-19937147316183/" > /dev/null 2>&1
/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1455138572.23-19937147316183/setup:3951: DeprecationWarning: object.__new__() takes no parameters
  return super(cls, subclass).__new__(subclass, *arguments, **keyword)
```

Here's the versions of python and ansible

```
$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.0.0.2
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

I have the same version of python on the server I'm attempting to deploy to and I do not have ansible installed on it.

Do I not have something installed or do I need to upgrade python or something else?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with python 2.6.6 on Centos 6.7.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found a 2-step process that allowed me to work with the CentOS 6 systems.

1. I had to install the `libselinux-python` package.
2. tell Ansible to use `paramiko` as the connection method.  I did this by putting all my CentOS 6 hosts in a group, and adding a group_vars file:

```
# file: inventory/group_vars/centos6
---
ansible_connection: paramiko
ansible_ssh_common_args:
```

Now I'm good to go.  I hope this helps you out.